# Strongly Correlated Materials: Theoretical Frameworks, Computational Techniques, and Machine Learning Breakthroughs in Matter Modeling

Tags: one-topic-per-answer, condensed-matter, machine-learning, electron-correlation

This is more of an opened discussion, recommendations, and experts views on the Strongly correlated materials.
Exploring the behavior of strongly correlated materials poses significant challenges in condensed matter physics. what are the theoretical frameworks and computational techniques used to accurately capture the intricate interplay of electron-electron interactions, spin dynamics, and lattice effects in these systems. Furthermore, what is the emerging role of machine learning and artificial intelligence in enhancing our understanding of complex phenomena such as high-temperature superconductivity and quantum magnetism. Provide specific examples of recent breakthroughs achieved through advanced matter modeling approaches that shed light on the fundamental physics underlying these intriguing materials.